# What are these "manager" attributes?

Tags: attributes, google-directory-api

The Google Admin SDK > Directory API has a few attributes that I'm not sure how they should be used, based on the descriptions on https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/search-users. Specifically, I'm wondering if anyone could clarify the use case for these attributes?

- managerId
- directManager
- directManagerId

We do map the "manager" attribute to the email address of a users' manager and this works well for the Gmail app to show the reporting structure.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Scrolling down the page a bit, I just noticed an example that helps.

Search for users with the same direct manager
directManager='bobjones@example.com'

Comment: Add the answer yourself, then.

Comment: If you find the answer please let us know